# how does boost avoid ABA issue on a 32 bit machine?

Tags: c++, boost, lock-free

I'm reading [**lock free**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/lockfree/rationale.html#lockfree.rationale.interprocess_support) part of boost documention,it says "using a fixed-sized array to store the internal nodes" to avoid prevent **ABA issue** on a 32bit machine. can some one give me a hint where this part exits in the source code? the whole boost project is too big for me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a pointer to the source, but the documentation seems clear enough to me.

Instead of using a pointer-with-tag, they can use an index-with-tag when the size of the queue is known in advance. This way, instead of needing the entire width of a pointer (because a node could theoretically be allocated anywhere in the 32-bit virtual address space), they only need enough bits for the index value (which is 0-based) into an array of nodes that get allocated up front.

So, say you want a queue with a maximum of 65536 elements: Using pointers, you'd need 32-bits (or a few less if you can rely on allocations being aligned a certain way) to address the element, and then some more for the tag, which altogether doesn't fit into a single 32-bit word. But using indices, you only need 16-bits to address (well, index) all values from 0 to 65535. The rest of the 32-bit wide machine word can be used to store the tag value, and only a 32-bit wide CAS instruction is required at the hardware level.